# Copying a range of column using a loop

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want to copy all the columns of a worksheet in to another worksheet one below the another.

```
                                  Sheet A 

Column          A            B             C  ....................BL

             ValueA        ValueB       ValueC..................ValueBL
             ValueA2       ValueB2      ValueC2.................ValueBL2
                 .             .            .                        .
                 .             .            .                        .
             ValueA10       ValueB10     ValueC10...............ValueBL10

                                Target Sheet 

            Value A
               .
               .
            Value A10
            Value B
               . 
               .
            Value B10
            Value C
               .
               .
            Value C10
```

and so on. Basically each column has multiple values(rows) and there are hundreds of column. I want to copy all the columns one below the another. This will require a loop , but I don't understand as how to use it. Because

```
set ws1 As SheetA
set ws2 As Target  
With ws1
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
Lastrow = period.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i=1 to Lastcol
    ws1.Range("?" & lastrow).copy  ws2.Range("a65536").End(xlUP).Offset(1,0)
Next i
```

I am not getting as what to put instead of "?". Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Edit :

```
set ws1 As SheetA
set ws2 As Target  
With ws1
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
Lastrow = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Lastcol
    For l = 4 To lastrow
        ws1.Cells(l, i).Copy ws2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next l
Next i
```

My data starts from 4th row and that's the reason I start l from 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you need two FOR loops... one to loop through the columns then the rows.  Also, I would use "Cells" versus "Range" in this case, and use the column number in the loop.  There are also ways to lookup the first and last rows and columns, but you didn't ask about that...

```
Sub test()
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
Lastcol = 5
lastrow = 10

For i = 1 To Lastcol
    For l = 1 To lastrow
        ws1.Cells(l, i).Copy ws2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next l
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I get stuck in to a infinite loop. I added my lastrow and column definitions.  Can you please advice.

Comment: Looking over your example, the only reason you should be getting stuck in infinite loop is due to the row and column definitions not counting properly.  Have you placed a stop in your code or stepped through it to ensure the correct column and row counts are right?

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. It just takes like 2 hours for 80k rows, but works great